# Sourcing /root/.zshrc in Docker using current user

Tags: docker

I am trying to build my container for a root user and then run it with my user and source the `/root/.zshrc` from inside.

Here is a minimal example:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update 
RUN apt install --assume-yes --fix-broken \
    curl \
    wget \
    zsh

RUN echo EDITOR=vim >> /root/.zshrc

RUN chmod a+rx /root
CMD [ "source /root/.zshrc", "zsh"]
```

The invocation is as follows:

```sh
docker run --rm -it -v "$HOME/.ssh:$HOME/.ssh:ro" -v "$HOME/.netrc:$HOME/.netrc:ro" -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v /etc/shadow:/etc/shadow:ro -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro --user $UID:$UID foo_minimal
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```sh
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"source /root/.zshrc\": stat source /root/.zshrc: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: A container generally runs a single process (and not an interactive shell).  What do you want that single process to be?  If you want an interactive shell with the host filesystem and user identity, just directly run `zsh`; you don't need Docker for this.

Comment: (You are running the equivalent of the shell command `'source /root/.zshrc' zsh` as the main container command, though without a shell, and that doesn't really make sense.)

Comment: David, this is a minimal example of something bigger. I do need a container here.

Comment: As far as I can understand, source is a shell builtin command. So I cannot source before I run zsh..